# jquery works in external js file but not in view blade

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using laravel 5.5. When i am using jquery in external js file it works but when i write jquery inside the blade view it gives an error: $ not defined or found. I also checked by writing jquery in the layout file after loading the app.js file, it works. Jquery is only not working inside the blade. Jquery works inside the blade when i load a jquery. But then how is it working in external js and layout even after not loading jquery. So my concern is if jquery is loaded by default in laravel why it is not working inside blade ?

Here is my blade content:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
</div>
@endsection

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('lol');
})
</script>
```

Comment: do you import jquery to header or footer?

Comment: post your blade file contents here

Comment: It seems that your jquery file is loaded after executing your `$..` code.

Comment: no i am not importing jquery but still it works in external js and layout but not in blade

Comment: jquery is available in your `app.js` file. Try placing your code after importing `app.js`, it will work

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham no it should work beacuse jquery code is after importing app.js file which i think is the source of jquery

Comment: Post your blade file code, so that can help you better

Comment: show your blade file code

Comment: just a suggestion, best to wrap your script in a [verbatim block](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks). just in case.. and check on the finished html result. as the other comments/answers say, you might execute your code before the jquery loaded.

Comment: Anything outside of your section will not be rendered. You could use `@stack` in your `app.blade.php` and `@push` your code to it in your view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript code is outside any section, so it will not be rendered. A nice approach to rendering inline javascript in blade is to use `@stack` in your layout and then `@push` from any view extending the layout:

app.blade.php:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
[...]
@yield('content')
[...]
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
@stack('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

Your view (template.blade.php):

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
</div>
@endsection

@push('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('lol');
})
</script>
@endpush
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, do understand:

This does work:

```
<html>
 <header>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 </header>
 <body>

  <script>
   /* your js inline code here */
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

But a better solution is:

```
<html>
 <header>

 </header>
 <body>

  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
   /* your js inline code here */
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

This will not work:

```
<html>
 <header>

 </header>
 <body>  
  <script>
   /* your js inline code here */
  </script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```